# SharePoint 2010 workflow not starting after migration

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have SharePoint 2013 production environment where SharePoint 2010 workflow is running which was made in SharePoint Designer.

I moved site collection to another exact SharePoint 2013 DR environment and now I am unable to start that workflow. When you try to start workflow it says `Failed on start` and in detail it says `Workflow was cancelled by System account`

The existing workflow appears to be running as their status is in progress but I am not sure if they are actually working because only when the user to whom task is assigned, if he take some action, only then we will know if the existing ones are also working or not.

But new workflow instance is not being created. Even manually starting workflow doesn't work. I created a new SharePoint 2010 workflow on same list for testing and it is working fine so the problem is with the workflow which was migrated.

By the way I am logged in as `System Account` on this machine. So, what I did, I opened new browser instance using `Run as different user` and tried but same issue.

I also applied following fix in `web.config` but same problem.

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/rodneyviana/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working`

There isn't much information in the logs. How to diagnose and fix this issue?